# WAMP switcher (Windows Apache MySql & PHP)

Tags: windows, gratis, php, wamp

I am looking for a gratis Windows app to allow me to install and switch between different versions of PHP, possibly also MySql, although that is not so important. I don't care about switching Apache.

I am currently trying to develop a PHP application and cannot predict what version of PHP (and MySql) the end user will have installed.

I would like to be able to switch between PHP 5.x and 7.x and back at the click of a button and see how my application/website behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Laragon. You can install PHP, Apache, Mysql and MailCatcher easily, choosing versions that Laragon offers.

[Link to Laragon](https://laragon.org/)

Comment: This looks awesome! I will spend some time with it ASAP & come back to award the answer. Thank you very much; if it works as described, it is a total game changer

Answer (score 1):

I think [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is the best solution for you.

It is a very updated project with the latest versions also for 32 and 64 bits.

The easiest way to **switch** and **configure** the versions you choose.